# Comparing multiple string lengths in array Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

This is what's asked of us:

Ask the English version of the first names of three of your family members using showInputDialog() method of the JOptionPane class.
Display the name of the family member who has the longest first name as following.  (If there is a tie, just display one of the two.)
Daniel has the longest first name.

This is what I have so far and am stuck:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Foothill {      

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] names = new String[2];

    for(int x=0; x < 4; x++){  

        names[x] = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name"));

        for(int j=0; )
        }
    if();{

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The number with the greatest value is " + Max);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how to test the length of each string in the array and then compare the length of the strings within the array. I understand there are built-in methods to do this, but can someone please explain how to do this through iteration? Thanks!

Comment: It is not compilable code...

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to iterate over all names and compare the length using the .length() method.

Another solution is to compare the length each time you enter a string (only one for loop).
Here's an example :

```
int nb = 2;
String[] names = new String[nb];
int maxLength = -1; // Default value
for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    names[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name : ");
    // Compare the length of this name to the previous greatest length
    if (names[i].length() > maxLength) {
        // Change the maximum
        maxLength = names[i].length();
    }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The greatest value is " + maxLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all the names and use the `.length()`method in String:

```
String longest = "";
for (String name : names) {
    longest = name.length() > longest.length() ? name : longest;
}
```

This will iterate through your name list (`names`) and assign the longest to the variable `longest`

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple really.

```
String[] names = {
  "John",
  "Cassandra",
  "Tom"
};

String longest = names[0];
for(int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
    String name = names[i];
    if(name.length() > longest.length())
        longest = name;
}

// longest will be "Cassandra" here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] names = new String[3];
    int longest = 0;
    String longestName = "";

    for(int x=0; x < 3; x++){

        names[x] = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your gosh darned name"));

        if(names[x].length() > longest){
            longest= names[x].length();
            longestName = names[x];
        }

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, longestName +" has the longest name, it is " 
        + longest + "characters");

}
```

Comment: What if he types 5 names?

Comment: @JoaoMosquito OP specified that the "first names of **three** of your family members" would be inputted. Also the dialog box will only appear 3 times